# IOError when using imghdr module in Python

Tags: python, imghdr

This is my code used to check the format of files stored in many folders:

**check_image_format()**:

```
import imghdr as ih

def check_image_format(image_dir):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(image_dir):
        for image in files:
            format = ih.what(image)
            if format != 'jpeg' or format != 'png':
                return -1
    return 0
```

**main()**:

```
def main(_):
    # Check the correct format of images
    ret = check_image_format('img_dir')
    if(ret == -1):
         print("Some images are not in the correct format. Please check")
```

my `img_dir` is the root directory of others three subfolders containing the images I want to check.
When I launch the program I received this error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: img_1.jpg
```

But the file exists and is inside a subfolder.
What is the reason of this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build absolute path for your current image path:

```
import imghdr as ih

def check_image_format(image_dir):

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(image_dir):
        for image in files:
            format = ih.what(os.path.join(root, image))
            if format != 'jpeg' or format != 'png':
                return -1
    return 0
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! I forgot the absolute path problem.